# Deleting a single item from a C++ Doubly Linked List

Tags: c++, list, double

I have a class that is a Doubly Linked List class, containing the standard struct with one int data and two nodes prev and next. Within the class but outside the struct I also have the standard two nodes, head and tail. I have other functions, and so my doubly linked list is built. I now want to delete a single value in the doubly linked list, such as the data, using a class function. It can be an "index" or a value I'm looking for, either or. How can I do this? I end up just deleting the entire list when I try delete head. Here is my attempt:

```
void DLList::delItem ()
{
    while(head != NULL)
    {
        if(head->data == 1)
        {
            delete head;
        }
        else{
            head = head->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the constructor:

```
DLList::DLList()
{
    struct Node
    {
        int data;
        Node* prev;
        Node* next;
    };
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
}
```

I also have a function to print the values. It works once, but then no longer prints the values. I'm not sure if they're being deleted afterwards. Here is the printing function:

```
void DLList::print()
{
    Node* temp3 = head;
    while(temp3 != NULL)
    {
        cout << temp3->data << " ";
        temp3 = temp3->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Post the class code. If head is member of class, it will obviously delete the class.

Comment: if `head` is your real list head, then `head = head->next` will always screw your list up (and leak memory).

Answer (score 0):

Check out this article on CodeProject: [Implementing Doubly Linked List](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/668818/Implementing-a-Doubly-Linked-List-to-be-used-on-an)

BTW consider not inventing the wheel and using std::list